# Linearly independent over $\mathbb{Z}$, also linearly independent over $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be a set of vectors in $\mathbb{Z}^n$ that are linearly independent over $\mathbb{Z}$. Are they also linearly independent over $\mathbb{R}$ embedded in $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: Editing for the sake of placing a follow-up Q is not a good idea, in general. It is recommended to open a new post, possibly including a reference/link.
(And then undo the above edit.)

Comment: Thanks for the remark. I fixed it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

YES.

First observe that if $V$ is linearly independent of $\mathbb Z$ then it is linearly independent of $\mathbb Q$.

Next assume that
$$
c_1v_1+\cdots+c_kv_k=0, \quad c_1,\ldots, c_k\in\mathbb R. 
$$
The $c_j$'s span a vector space $X$ over $\mathbb Q$. That is
$$
X=\{q_1c_1+\cdots+q_nc_k : q_j\in\mathbb Q\}\subset\mathbb R.
$$
Say that $\dim_{\mathbb Q}X=\ell\le k$, and $b_1,\ldots, b_\ell$ a basis of $X$.
Then $c_i=\sum_{j=1}^\ell q_{ij}b_j$, for some $q_{ij}\in\mathbb Q$. (The $c_i$'s are uniquely such expressed.) Then
$$
0=\sum_{i=1}^k c_iv_i=\sum_{i=1}^k\sum_{j=1}^\ell q_{ij}b_j v_i=\sum_{j=1}^\ell\left(\sum_{i=1}^kq_{ij}v_i\right)b_j
$$
If we take the $m-$component of the vectors above ($m=1,\ldots,n$) we obtain
$$
0=\sum_{j=1}^\ell\left(\sum_{i=1}^kq_{ij}v_{im}\right) b_j
$$
This implies that $\sum_{i=1}^kq_{ij}v_{im}=0$ for all $m=1,\ldots,n$ and all $j=1,\ldots,\ell$, since the $b_j$ are linearly independent over $\mathbb Q$.
Hence
$$
\sum_{j=1}^\ell\left(\sum_{i=1}^kq_{ij}v_{i}\right) b_j=0.
$$
And as the $v_i$'s are also linearly independent over $\mathbb Q$, then the $q_{ij}$ also are zero. Therefore
$$
c_i=\sum_{j=1}^\ell q_{ij}b_j=0,\quad\text{for all $i=1,\ldots,k$}
$$

Comment: The proof is really nice, but I think that there is a small mistake. When you say that $\sum_{j=1}^\ell \left( \sum_{i=1}^k q_{ij}v_i\right)b_j=0$ implies that $\sum_{i=1}^k q_{ij}v_i=0$, you take that sum to be a rational coefficient of $b_j$. But that's not true, it is a vector in $\mathbb{Q}^n$

Comment: @57Jimmy I have improved my answer a bit.